# Getting can't convert int to str error in my code can't figure out why

Tags: python, string, while-loop, int, find

My code is supposed to take a pin number and change it into an "easy to remember" arrangement of vowels and consonants

```
def alphapinEncode(pin):
    vowels = "aeiou "
    consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz "
    alphaPin = " "
    while pin > 0:
        newPin = pin // 100
        pinRemain = pin % 100
        vowelToFind = pinRemain % 5
        pinVowel = vowels.find(vowelToFind)
        pinConsonant = consonants.find(pinRemain // 5)
        pin = newPin
        alphaPin = alphaPin + pinVowel + pinConsonant

    return alphaPin
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: also I know I havent added the consonantToFind section yet but it won't get past the vowel section since it can't convert int to str so I didnt feel the need to add it until I get that working

Comment: When you % 100 if will give you the last 2 digits which will be between 00-99 and if you % that by 5 you will get something between 0-5 which is the amount of vowels and if you // that by 5 you will get something between 0-19 which is the amount of consonants

Comment: You should be iterating over the PIN *as a string* and not doing mathematical operations on it. By treating it as a number, if my PIN is, say 0024, you are only going to give me the "easy-to-remember" code for the 24 part, when I need to enter all four digits for it to work.

Comment: well the idea is that after you find the "easy to remember part" for the last 2 digits the // 100 portion that becomes newPin is the rest of the pin so when the function returns it will run again for the rest of your pin and so on until their is no numbers left

Comment: Please edit the clarifications into the original question; that makes the Q&A more useful for future SO users.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with these 2 lines:

```
vowelToFind = pinRemain % 5
pinVowel = vowels.find(vowelToFind)
```

In this case `vowelToFind` is an integer, and `vowels` is a string. The `find` method of `str` accepts a *string* argument, and returns its position in the string - you are passing an *integer* instead. You aren't even looking to find a substring within `vowels`, you are simply looking to retrieve the character at index `vowelToFind`. I believe you ought to do the following instead:

```
vowelToFind = pinRemain % 5
pinVowel = vowels[vowelToFind]
```

**Note**

I'm solving the specific "int to str" error that you asked about. I'm not sure about the rest of the logic you're using to generate an "easy-to-remember" character sequence.

Comment: this worked! Thanks so much. With the example we did it class we were only using string so when we switched to integers in the project it threw me off a bit

Comment: My pleasure, brochacho!! :D

Comment: also the rest of the logic is based on the guidelines given to me in the project I am doing, not my own  logic